# Can we change email content for bcc only Using SendGrid Personalization?

Tags: asp.net, email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have an email for customer, Its bcc we have the Subscriber's company Email.Email Contain a link to web page.Now the problem is the link is passing `IsCustomer=true` which becomes the reason for a function to be executed.I want to replace `IsCustomer=true` with `IsCustomer=false` or disable the link for BCC only.
I do not have an option to send two separate emails. 
Technically, the requirement seems weird to me as why we should be able to change the email content of same email for recipient and BCC.
I have studied the personalizations topic [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations/#sending-two-different-emails-to-two-different-groups-of-recipients) and I am doubtful about this.
Is there any way to achieve that?